# ArrayList—Implementation of indexOf(T t) Method

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

How can I implement such a method in Java? I want a generic example and while I understand the complexities involved in such comparison (duplicates, etc.), any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Iterate through the elements... The JDK source code is available by the way.

Comment: Have a look at the [`ArrayList.indexOf(Object)`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html#line.220) source code.

Comment: It's here, but it's indexOf(Object o)  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) is the source code you are looking for.
Below is a snippet containing the method you are after:

Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

```
 public int indexOf(Object o) {
     if (o == null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             if (elementData[i]==null)
                 return i;
     } else {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                 return i;
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ArrayList.indexOf(Object)`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/ArrayList-source.html#line.220) source code will provide the solution I seek.